# How to show custom circular view on screen on bases of latitude and longitude

Tags: android, draw, points

I want to show this type of view:

[image]

I don't know how to create this type of view. Please give any idea how I can create this.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: i am ok with circular view but how to show these like a marker and base on latitude and longitude but don't want to show map.

Comment: If you are not implementing drag to zoom, then you can directly implement it using x-y co-ordinates of the screen

Comment: don't want to  drag to zoom.

Comment: situation resolved by using tiles on google map..

Comment: Is it  possible without using google map or third party ?